# Is there a way to change icons in the ant design image preview operations?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using the Image component from ant design which also has a preview and in top right corner there are operations to zoom rotate etc for the image but I want to change these icons, I found there is an icons property for the preview config props but I can't figure out how the structure is because it is not given in the documentation.

```
<Image
        src={imageUrl}
        preview={{
          visible: state.visible,
          onVisibleChange: (visible) => closeModal(),
          destroyOnClose: true,
          icons: [] -- How do I add custom icons here?
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export const icons = {
  rotateLeft: <RotateLeftOutlined />,
  rotateRight: <RotateRightOutlined />,
  zoomIn: <ZoomInOutlined />,
  zoomOut: <ZoomOutOutlined />,
  close: <CloseOutlined />,
  left: <LeftOutlined />,
  right: <RightOutlined />,
};
```

default icons